# How to prevent api requests after 1st request fails with 401 response and re-execute only after refreshing token in angular

Tags: angular, error-handling, access-token, interceptor, http-status-code-401

Context: I have a Angular application with oAuth access_token authentication and guards protecting the routes which is working as expected. I have an auth interceptor which will catch the 401 Unauthorised status code and refresh the access_token with refresh_token.

Issue: When refreshing the access_token, the other two requests out of the three will also fail with 401 Unauthorised. Can we prevent api requests after 1st request fails with 401 response and re-execute only after refreshing access_token?

I tried pooling the request after the first 401 error, but the other two calls are not waiting for refresh_token api to finish.

Any suggestions or guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks! in advance

Answer (score -1):

Send the first request and wait until response.

```
private static accessTokenError$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

Set new token on next requests.

```
if (!JwtInterceptor.accessTokenError$.getValue()) {
          // isRrefreshing = true;
          JwtInterceptor.accessTokenError$.next(true);

          return this.authService.getNewRefreshToken().pipe(
            switchMap((newTokens: any) => {
              const transformedReq = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set(
                  "Authorization",
                  `bearer ${newTokens.data.token}`
                ),
              });
              JwtInterceptor.accessTokenError$.next(false);
              return next.handle(transformedReq);
            }), catchError(error => {
              return throwError(error);
            })
          );
        } else {
           // If it's not the firt error, it has to wait until get the access/refresh token
           return this.waitNewTokens().pipe(
            switchMap((event: any) => {
                // Clone the request with new Access Token
                const newRequest = req.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                        Authorization: `bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
                    }
                });
                return next.handle(newRequest);
            })
        );
        }
```

This is the method which will await requests until the first one getting response.

```
 private waitNewTokens(): Observable<any> {
const subject = new Subject<any>();
const waitToken$: Subscription = JwtInterceptor.accessTokenError$.subscribe((error: boolean) => {
    if(!error) {
        subject.next();
        waitToken$.unsubscribe();
    }
});
return subject.asObservable();}
```

Comment: Will this work for multiple async calls? If yes could u please provide working jsfiddle sample if possible.

Comment: Yes this one works when token expires and in the mean time multiple request comes at a time asynchronously. Hopefully [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jayadul/38atb57r/16/) my help you.